# Blender 3.0 Add Mesh (Icosphere)

Tags: mesh, add-on

I'm a beginner watching v2.x Youtube Tutorials. In them there is a add menu to define basic structure of the iconsphere.
(Object Mode > Add > Mesh > Icosphere > [enter]. No menu, just the sphere.

Where is the menu in 3.0, or what is the equivalent? Add-ons? modifier?

Comment: Are you looking for this menu? https://i.stack.imgur.com/No129.png

Comment: Yes, that's the one. The answer below also told me where to find it - so grats to both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as you've added the icosphere you should see a settings dialog in the bottom left of the 3D window. You may have to click the down arrow (indicated) to expand it.

[image] Note that you must alter any of the settings before moving or applying any other transformation to the icosphere. You can however bring back the dialog with <kbd>F9</kbd> if it's disappeared but only if you've not changed anything else in the interim.
This applies to most other objects too.

Comment: The dialog was disappearing under my zoom add-on. I can just see its top. But now I've got it - thank you so much

Comment: Quite a few folks haven't even noticed it's there **without* any other addon dialogs in the way! :^)

Comment: Thanks again - for the F9 tip.