# Another Noise Tool - Landscape Menu

Tags: objects

Absolute blender newbie here. When I add a landscape mesh, I automatically see a menu to the left with a lot of different options (operator presets for example. Once I click off and try to click back on, I don't see it anymore. I'm just wondering how I can see it again. Screenshot for reference:[image]

Comment: This applies to adding **any** mesh in Blender, not just the Landscape one. See my answer in this posting: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/251703/blender-3-0-add-mesh-icosphere/251706#251706

Comment: Hey thanks for the pointer! I tried F9, but it still didn't come back. I didn't change anything in the interim, just clicked off then clicked back on. I'm running M2 MacBook Pro, wondering if this has any impact.

Comment: Even if you just go in and out of edit mode without actually changing anything you won't be able to get that settings dialog back.

Comment: Oh ok. So Blender just expects you to get all of those parameters right the first time. From then on, you just need to use the default editing tools to the right? It's just a bit confusing because it would make sense for a simple object like a cube, but terrain is highly specific and it would be nice to have all that functionality at all times. Thanks for all your help btw.

Comment: Correct! Once you've added an object and set its initial parameters with that dialog there's no way to change the original topology.